# Disable JFrame but Want Access to Menu Windows

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu

I dont know how to make this with simple and easy code.
I can just go to each piece of my code and use setEnabled to false on each component, but I want a easy way.

I want to disable the entire frame, but still want to close/maximize/minize it. do you understand?

And if I use setEnabled(false) on my frame, it disables that options too, the options of windows menu bar you know?

Thanks alot in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Simple,Put all your components in a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and disable the JPanel :-)

Comment: I tested setEnabled(false) on my JMenuBar and its not working... why?
I can still access to the menu :s

Comment: ehhh ... to reach which goal? (Slightly confused on the required vs. experienced). You know that disabling a container does _not_ disable its children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a code snippet like below. Insert this method/routine in a utility class. Since the method is static you can call it without that class's instance. And make invocations to this method to enable/disable components (menu items, buttons, text fields etc.)

```
// Let's say you have a JFrame object called myFrame 
// and a reference to its content pane.
// Container container = myFrame.getContentPane();

public static void toggleAbilities(Container container, boolean enabled)
{
  Component[] components = container.getComponents();
  for(Component component: components)
     component.setEnabled( enabled );
}
```

If you get stuck, I can post overall working code as well.
(Toggling the ability of a set of buttons in a JFrame)

Comment: no, that's not what you want to do ;-) In all but the most trivial GUIs enablement management requires some effort, typically bound to some domain state (think f.i. a save action enabled only if an open file had changed) Unconditionally disable all will wreck that binding

Comment: I already made it working , I put all my components on a Component vector, and then I just have a static function "like" (not equal) yours :)
And its working, just add to make more code :s
I was looking for a less code solution, but never mind ;)
thanks anyway guys.